# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): moralis__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Moralis.start is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, moralis

I'm getting:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): moralis__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.Moralis.start is not a function
```

In my front end, I'm using the [react-moralis](https://github.com/MoralisWeb3/react-moralis) framework.

```
(anonymous function)
src/hooks/useMoralis/_useMoralisIntit.ts:41
  38 |   }
  39 | 
  40 |   setIsInitializing(true);
> 41 |   await Moralis.start({ serverUrl, appId });
     | ^  42 |   setIsInitializing(false);
  43 |   setIsInitialized(true);
  44 | },
```

The code worked on `0.2.3` but breaking on `0.2.6`, what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

The `Moralis.start` piece was added in a recent release of `moralis`, so it's likely you are using packages that are out of sync.

You need to update both `react-moralis` and `moralis`

```
yarn add react-moralis moralis
```

This will update both to the latest edition.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a new function and `react-moralis` is using the Moralis version that you have installed. You need to update `moralis` to version `>0.0.92`